# MongoDB get the array element count based on the condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For the given structure I need to find out the count of the `likes` array based on the unique `slug` value

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
  "name" : ["Name"],
  "likes" : ["emp1"],
  "slug": 'slugabcd'
 }
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
  "name" : ["Another ", "Name"],
  "likes" : ["emp1","emp2","emp4"],
  "slug": 'slugxyz'
}
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
      "name" : ["Another ", "Name"],
      "slug": 'slugpqr'
}
```

Here is my code but not working

```
db.blog.aggregate({slug:"slugxyz"},{$project:{NumberOfItemsInArray:{$size:"likes"}}}).count();
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Will more than one document have the same slug value? If not you can just get length of array right?

Comment: all the docs slug should be unique, how to get the length of `likes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any query stage:

```
db.blog.aggregate({$project:{slug : "$slug", numberOfLikes:{$size:"$likes"}}})
```

Comment: `db.blog.aggregate({$project:{slug : "$slug", numberOfLikes:{"$size":{"$ifNull":["$likes",[]]}}}})` I hope this should work more. Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
const pipeline = [
{ 
 $group: {
    _id: "$slug",
    likesCount: {$sum: {$size: "$likes"}}
 }
]
```

Here we are grouping by the unique "slug" value and counting the size of "likes" array field.